# Emacs specific region read only

Tags: emacs

How does one make a specific region in a text file read only when using emacs. I know ctrl+X+Q
to make the whole file a read only.

I am currently writing a code and I do not want to modify by accident the first 40 lines of my code while working on lines 41 and upwards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use text properties:

```
(defun set-region-read-only (begin end)
  (interactive "r")
  (add-text-properties begin end '(read-only t)))
```

Relevant Docs:

[Text-Properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Properties.html#Text-Properties)

[Changing Properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Properties.html#Changing-Properties)

[Special Properties (like read-only)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Properties.html#Special-Properties)

Comment: Ironically, that modifies the buffer :) Maybe it's fine to wrap it with `(let ((modified (buffer-modified-p)))` ... `(set-buffer-modified-p modified)))` ?

Comment: Yeah. But it gets better: Removing read-only is real fun™, because removing the property again modifies or would if it wasn't read-only :)

Comment: Also note (quoted from that third link): "Since changing properties counts as modifying the buffer, it is not possible to remove a read-only property unless you know the special trick: bind inhibit-read-only to a non-nil value and then remove the property. See Read Only Buffers." (edit: Ha. Snap :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `narrow-to-region` (`C-x n n`) to narrow the buffer just to the part you want to change.  Then you won't see or be able to change the region you don't want to change.

Comment: In addition you can use `C-x 4 c` (`clone-indirect-buffer`) to get an additional view on the file which can be read-only and un/narrowed independently of the original buffer. Hence you could have one buffer narrowed and writeable, and another read-only and showing the full file. `C-x n w` to widen (un-narrow), btw :)

Comment: It's worth reading the details on this feature: `M-:` `(info "(emacs) Indirect Buffers")` `RET`

Answer (score 0):

You can also apply highlight-changes-mode. That way you can see which text is changed as it is in different color.   narrow-to-region is a good solution. You can also use that with 2 buffer, so you can see the read-only text too, if needed.