# emacs remove region read-only

Tags: emacs, elisp

Closely related to [Emacs specific region read only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410125/emacs-specific-region-read-only) how do you *remove* the read only property on a region of text in a buffer.

For example, if you are using a python shell in emacs and accidentally print out a huge list and would like to remove the output from your buffer.

Comment: Curious to learn which condition makes the output from Python shell read-only.

Comment: @AndreasRöhler And it's not every line, just 1 in 10 or so. It was a list of 2 layer deep nested tuples with a mix of lists, ints, and ndarrays.  I think the specific lines that were marked readonly were the first lines of the array print out.

Comment: AFAIU this should not happen from python-mode's side. Would like to see some example code. In any case solutions are interesting and helpful :)

Comment: @AndreasRöhler Ping me in a month when I will have a bit more time.  My guess is that comint is trying to be too clever.  Just starting the shell will give some read-only bits of the shell buffer (try to ctrl-k the In[] prompts).

Comment: Assume the idea was to protect the prompt from being deleted unwillingly by user. Remember having seen it, but can't get it now, neither with plain comint, nor python-mode. Okay... maybe let's close this.

Comment: @AndreasRöhler Also, using ipython, not strait python....is there an issue open for this somewhere?  The comments on a SO question is definitely not the right place to have this conversation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the following. It's similar to tcaswell's answer, but deals with the buffer modification issue.

```el
(defun set-region-read-only (begin end)
  "Sets the read-only text property on the marked region.

Use `set-region-writeable' to remove this property."
  ;; See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410125
  (interactive "r")
  (with-silent-modifications
    (put-text-property begin end 'read-only t)))

(defun set-region-writeable (begin end)
  "Removes the read-only text property from the marked region.

Use `set-region-read-only' to set this property."
  ;; See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410125
  (interactive "r")
  (with-silent-modifications
    (remove-text-properties begin end '(read-only t))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Following the cryptic comment under read-only in [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Properties.html#Special-Properties), to *remove* read-only from a region you just need:

```
(defun remove-region-read-only (begin end)
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
    (remove-text-properties begin end '(read-only t)))
  )
```