# Why can't I edit text in Emacs buffer *hmoccur* after I disable read-only?

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 25.1, Helm package.

Suppose I has some text that has word **test**. And I run command "helm-occur" to find this word. Here result:
[image]

So, now I want to save result to buffer *hmoccur*. I use **C-x C-s**.
So here result.
[image]

As you can see this buffer is read only. So I use command **read-only-mode** to disable read only. Here result:
[image]

And now I want to edit this buffer(add letter "a"). 
But I get the next strange message (**a is undefined**). And as result not print letter "a"
:[image]

Comment: Why I can't edit text in buffer *hmoccur* ?

Comment: Emacs seems to make a distinction between: "Buffer is read only" vs. "text is read-only." See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24565068/emacs-text-is-read-only#30906336